# How to GroupBy data in Linq to SQL query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I've got a problem in getting my groupby's right in a Linq to SQL query.

I have 3 tables: `Customers`, `Orders` and `OrderItems`.  The `OrderItems` contain the quantity and price of the items purchased.

Now I simply would like to list all the customers with the total price of all orders.
I have (amongst a number of other tries) this, but it's not compiling.  There is no `TotalPrice` item in the **Intellisense** where I have the **???** in the last line.

```
var q = (from c in db.Customers
        join o in db.Orders on c.ID equals o.Customer
        //join oi in db.OrderItems on o.ID equals oi.OrderID
        group c by new {c.CustomerName, TotalPrice = o.OrderItems.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price)} into groupby
        select groupby);

foreach (var cust in q)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", cust.Min(x => x.CustomerName), cust.Sum(x => x.???);
```

The (easy, understandable, straight forward and simple) SQL query will look like this:

```
SELECT C.ID, MIN(CustomerName) CustomerName, SUM(Quantity * Price) OrderPrice
FROM Customers C 
        INNER JOIN ORDERS O ON C.ID = O.Customer
        INNER JOIN OrderItems OI ON O.ID = OI.OrderID
GROUP BY C.ID
```

Comment: It can be done much simple with LinQ if you have foreign keys within tables. Do you have them? Or you just know what field whould it be?

Comment: Yes, I do have foreign keys.  So the foreign keys can be used.

Comment: Actually what you have done in SQL is not `OrderPrice` but `TotalOrderPriceByCustomer` is that what are you trying to achive? and i don't know why you use `MIN(CustomerName)` and not add `CustomerName` to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Adding the CustomerName to GroupBy will achieve the same result as the Name is not part of the PK.  My (possible incorrect) understanding is that the Min will execute quicker.  And yes, I am looking for TotalOrderPricePerCustomer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can mess with names, but here is **LinQ** expression with **Extension methods** syntax that match your **SQL**:

```
        var q = db.Customers
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            x.ID,
            x.CustomerName,
        }, (x, group) => new
        {
            Id = x.ID,
            CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
            TotalPrice = group.Select(y => y.Orders.Sum(z => z.OrderItems.Sum(a => a.Price * a.Quantity)))
        });

        foreach (var cust in q)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", cust.CustomerName, cust.TotalPrice);
```

Comment: Well, I must say that it seems to be working so I'll accept as answer.  Couple of things in the solution that I'm not understanding yet, but I have to believe there must be a simple solution as well out there. Will post if I find something that I can wrap my head around :-). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

This is sums by Customer and Order

```
var orders = (from c in context.Customers
    join o in context.Orders on c.custid equals o.custid
    join od in context.OrderDetails on o.orderid equals od.orderid
      select new
              {
                  c.custid,
                  o.orderid,
                  od.qty,
                  od.unitprice
              }).GroupBy(c => new
                          {
                              c.custid,
                              c.orderid
                          }).Select(c => new
                          {
                              c.Key.custid,
                              c.Key.orderid,
                              Summ = c.Sum(d => d.qty * d.unitprice)
                          }).ToList();
```

This is sums by Customer only

```
            var orders = (from c in context.Customers
                          join o in context.Orders on c.custid equals o.custid
                          join od in context.OrderDetails on o.orderid equals od.orderid
                          select new
                          {
                              c.custid,
                              od.qty,
                              od.unitprice
                          }
                          ).GroupBy(c => new
                          {
                              c.custid,
                          }).Select(c => new
                          {
                              c.Key.custid,
                              Summ = c.Sum(d => d.qty * d.unitprice)
                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working for me:

```
var q = (from c in db.Customers
        join o in db.Orders on c.ID equals o.Customer
        join oi in db.OrderItems on o.ID equals oi.OrderID
        group new {c, o.ID, oi.Quantity, oi.Price} by new {c.ID, c.CustomerName} into grp
        let TotalPrice = grp.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price)
        select new 
        {
            CustomerID = grp.Key.ID,
            CustomerName = grp.Key.CustomerName,
            TotalPrice
        });
```

and

```
var q = (from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.ID equals o.Customer
            join oi in db.OrderItems on o.ID equals oi.OrderID
            group new { CustomerID = c.ID, CustomerName = c.CustomerName, Price = oi.Price, Quantity = oi.Quantity} by c.ID into grp
            select new 
            { 
                ID = grp.Key, 
                CustomerName = grp.Min(x => x.CustomerName), 
                TotalPrice = grp.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity)
            });
```